# How to sort data in spring jpa?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I am writing my first web-application project about rental a cars in java using Spring Boot, Hibernate and MySql.
In my app I want to have smth like sort methods. I made that by add in my view an input where users can type e.g type or model of car. I want to get result of query e.g type='sportcar' and from this result I want to sort data e.g by price DESC or ASC.

Here is my code of view

```
<body>
<form action="get" method="get">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="inputState">Sort by</label>
      <select name="sortMethod" id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select sort method</option>
        <option value="priceDESC">price desc</option>
        <option value="priceASC">price asc</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </div>

</form>

<form action="get" method="get">
    Type:   <input type="text" name="type">
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<form action="get" method="get">
    Brand:  <input type="text" name="brand"/>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<form action="get" method="get">
    Model:  <input type="text" name="model"/>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Here is my code of Controller

```
@GetMapping(path = "/get")
public String getAllCars(ModelMap modelMap) {

    cars = carRepository.findAll();
    modelMap.addAttribute("cars", cars);
    return "car";
}

@GetMapping(path = "/get", params = "sortMethod")
public String getAllCars(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "priceASC", required = false) String sortMethod,
        ModelMap modelMap) {

    String parameterOfSort = "";
    String wayOfSort = "";
    char c;

    for (int i = 0; i < sortMethod.length(); i++) {
        c = sortMethod.charAt(i);
        if (c >= 64 && c <= 90)
            wayOfSort += c;
        else if (c >= 97 && c <= 122)
            parameterOfSort += c;
    }

    Sort.Direction sortType = Sort.Direction.valueOf(wayOfSort);

    cars = carRepository.findAll(Sort.by(sortType, parameterOfSort));
    modelMap.addAttribute("cars", cars);
    return "car";
}

@GetMapping(path = "/get", params = "type")
public String getCarsByType(@RequestParam String type, ModelMap modelMap) {

    cars = carRepository.findCarByType(type);
    modelMap.addAttribute("cars", cars);
    return "car";
}
```

I think that my approach isn't correct. How can I modify my code to get satisfying result and good approach for this situation?

Comment: Don't reinvent the `Sort` class (which Spring supports using directly as a controller parameter, parsing both the property and direction for you).

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- oh, thanks I didn't know about this kind of magic in spring :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [spring jpa doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference), JPA support sort, in your case:

```java
public interface CarRepository extend CrudRepository<Car, Long> {

  List<Car> findByTypeOrderByPriceDesc(String type); //sportsCar, order by price desc
}
```